# How do you create and index Apple Watch interface pages

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I'm creating a watch app that has multiple pages using the same interface controller.  I would like to know how my custom manager object can index each controller.

I've tried adding a IBInspectable index set in the storyboard, but the controllers report their pageIndex as 0 after init & awake calls.

I know I could create subclasses that return their own index, but that seems messy.

Comment: Do you mean how to build an interface based on pages using storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no control on the index, is just a matter of adding them to an array in the order you want.

This is how you present pages:

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:controllers contexts:contexts];
```

Both controller and contexts are arrays. The pages will be presented with the order they have in the array.

If you will present multiple controllers of the same type, create a for loop and add them to the controller array. The same with the contexts.

controllers[0] will use the contexts[0] and so on.